# About Timer and Timer Task in Java

Tags: java

Let's say I have a currently running Timer with a scheduled TimerTask.  If I call `timer.cancel()` does that kill all of the variables in my TimerTask as well or do I have to wait for the GC?  Also, can I reassign it with a new task after calling `.cancel()`

```
timer.cancel();
timer = new Timer();
messageTimer = new MessageTask();
timer.schedule(messageTimer, 1000, 1000);
```

or is there a more suitable way to replace the timer task in the original timer object, or something I'm not even thinking of?

Thanks -T

Comment: @EvanM Thanks!  Forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, memory is *only* reclaimed via GC, but as a developer, your variables are useless (and ready for garbage collection) once you have no more references to them.

In your example, you are creating a new Timer by reassigning it with =. If there are no more references, the old one will eventually get garbage collected.